# How to install OS X Yosemite on MacBook (with empty hard drive) from Ubuntu or Windows?

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, unix

Every time I search for how to create and install OS X on a MacBook from Windows I get a lot of Hackintosh videos, videos saying to use a Mac to create the installer, or even how to install in VirtualBox which are not what I want to do.

I have a late 2010 MacBook that has no operating system on it. I know I can install and run Yosemite on it, but I don't have a spare Mac to create a USB installer.

I'm currently using Windows and Ubuntu. My MacBook's hard drive is empty and I'd like to be able to create the Yosemite installer on either Windows or Ubuntu to install Yosemite on my Mac.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I purchased a USB installer from [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/151872130930?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT). I got it in the mail today and when I tried installing from the USB it dropped at some package file. I now have a Recovery HD drive with Reinstall OS X as an option but after I sign into App Store it says, "This item is temporarily unavailable. Try again later". Same problem over and over all day..

Comment: I'd go into the Apple Store and ask them to install it for you. That way it'd be completely legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly do an Internet Recovery with a new drive. Press Command + R on start up:

From [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314):

> Newer Macs include the ability to start up directly from an Internet-based version OS X Recovery. Your Mac automatically uses this feature when the Recovery System on the startup drive isn't available. For example, if your startup drive encounters an issue, or if your startup drive has been replaced or erased. Internet Recovery lets you start your Mac directly from Apple's servers. Starting up from this system performs a quick test of your memory and hard drive to check for hardware issues.

If this doesn't work, taking it to the Apple store will be your best bet.

Comment: I just wanted to say that originally this method did not work. I would get a folder icon with a question mark blinking. However I replaced my hard drive and now I was able to install Yosemite on my Macbook. Turned out my hard drive was dead.

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling provides a link to, appropriately, this question @ [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225820/how-to-create-a-os-x-mountain-lion-bootable-usb-drive-on-ubuntu). This solution is for Mountain Lion, so perhaps a bit of sleuthing on your part can find out if it's applicable as-is for Yosemite, needs a little tweaking to work, or just won't work at all.

I don't Ubuntu, so YMMV with this link.